# How do i put validation on checkbox with MVC3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created the register page on mvc3 razor. I want to put the validation on user notification field. Below is my code.

```
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Student Notification ?")]
 [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You gotta tick the box!")]
 public Boolean UserNotification { get; set; }
```

Below is my register page view

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserNotification)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model =>model.UserNotification)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserNotification)
    </div>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </p>
```

So when i will click the button, there should be validation message there ..

Comment: Just a question but why are you using Boolean instead of bool for your model? Also I am assuming this but your register is within a @using (Html.BeginForm()) correct?

Comment: Since a `boolean` property can only have values `true and `false` and can vever be `null`, then your `[Required]` can be removed (it does nothing) and `[Range]` with `true to true` wont work with client side validation. In the POSTmethod, if the value is `false`, add a `ModelState` error and return the view so its displayed

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your datatype of the property `UserNotification`. Change:

```
public Boolean UserNotification { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public bool UserNotification { get; set; }
```

There is a lot difference between `Boolean` and `bool`.